# Applying on picture to a mesh but not the same picture to every face of the mesh

Tags: texturing

In cycle render.
There does not seem to be an option to wrap a texture around a mesh like in blender render.
In blender render I can wrap just ON texture to lets say a sphere.
In cycle render it is the same texture to every FACE of the mesh.
How could I have the same result in cycle like in blender render?

Thanks
armin

Ok, so the question was not clear:)
Sorry my friends.

I just want to take a texture and wrap it arround a mesh the same way
as if to take a drawn picture on paper and wrap it arround, lets say a football .
The football has faces.
At the moment, when using cycle render, I don´t knwo how to wrap this texture picture arround the football in on pice.
At the moment it cycle render puts the picture of the  texture on every face of the foodball

I don´t want that.
Hope that helps:)

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean . . . could you please clarify a little?

Comment: I think you should either unwrap your mesh to make image texture be wrapped around mesh or use `Object` texture coordinates. See this answer - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles for more details