# Textures appears in Blender Render but missing in Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, blender-internal-render-engine

I have the following object loaded in Blender Render Mode 
[image]

However, in Cycles Render my UV map disappears 
[image]

Is there a way to get around this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Blend file link? Might help to check your specific settings.

Comment: How familiar are you with the Cycles render engine? [Does this related link solve your problem](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles)? @KevinLiang

Comment: You can't just switch to cycles and expect everything to still work because Blender Render and Cycles are two completely different render engines.

Answer (score 5):

Blender Cycles and Blender Internal are two completely independent rendering systems with different settings and material definitions.

Your UV Maps did not disappear, you just have to recreate your materials using the Cycles material nodes system.

Have in mind that even after recreating them, the Blender viewport does not support displaying material previews for cycles, only basic preview of image based textures, so you will only get to see them upon rendering or on interactive viewport render.

Comment: Shift + Z works for a slow but quicker than a full on render though, if i'm correct.

Comment: That's correct, it will create a basic preview of UV mapped image based textures, but no other type of textures or material properties are currently supported.

Answer (score 3):

UV Maps don't disappear. What's happening is that Blender Internal Shaders are very different from Cycles shaders. So if you switch from BI to Cycles, you have to set up your shaders for cycles. They're not converted automatically. For a simple diffuse shader with your image texture, you'd first need to press the Use Nodes button, since Cycles materials are node based. A diffuse shader will be created by default. Then for the color input there's a little icon to the right. Click it and select image texture. Select your image, and for the vector input select UV (under texture coordinate). That will give you a basic cycles shader setup that will render your image texture using your uv map.