# How can I add an image to a texture in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials

I would like to make cat's eyes. I did the cat in Cycles Render and the cat has different materials all over it.

[image]

I made the eyes in Photoshop. 
I want to add the eyes like a texture in Cycles Render if it is possible.

Comment: Have you tried moving so that you are viewing the cat head on, _tab_bing into edit mode for both eyes, keying _U_, and selecting _Project from View (Bounds)_? From there, you should be able to go to the _UV Image Editor_, load in your image, and align the projected mesh. You should also be able to create a simple material. Look (here)[http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles] for more.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Idle Chit-chat

I don't see any reason why you should not be able to simply unwrap the eyes and add in your texture, as I said in my comment. I will, however, elaborate here.

### Materials

I will use a sphere to represent the eye (smooth shading), and the following eye texture from [Google](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/Eye_I.jpg) (full size linked).

[image]

With the sphere selected, go to the *Materials* tab in the *Properties panel*. *+ New* a material to the sphere. Go into the *Node editor*, and use the setup shown.

[image]

Now, go to the sphere in the *3D Viewport*. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode, <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> to front view, and <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> to orthographic view. Press <kbd>U</kbd> and select *Project from View (Bounds)*. Split the screen into a *3D Viewport* and a *UV Image Editor* by dragging the marks in the top-right corner to the left. Make sure you are still in edit mode. Open the image of the eye through the toolbar at the bottom of the *UV Image Editor*. The orange should already be aligned over the eye.

### Final Notes

For whatever reason, the eye did not show up right from the pure UV editing, so I had to add the *Mapping* node to the node setup.

Here is the .blend file:

[image]