# v2.77a - Textured object not updating when manually changing UV coordinates

Tags: texturing, uv

I am experimanting with texturing simple objects. My idea is to use very small textures. So I manually resized and moved the UV coordinates to be inside the pixels. You can see on the screenshot I have uploaded.

[image: Blender screenshot of texturing simple cross]

Unfortunately they do not seem to update. I have zero idea why, any hints or tips will be appreciated.

[Edit]: I have put all obj faces that should be red over the red in the texture (neatly arranged without overlapping). I have moved all the faces that should be black on the top (this time I did not arrange them as it did not help with the red).

I expect all front and back of the cross to become red and the sides to be black.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're seeing, that you don't expect to see. If you can try to provide more information about what you see that is unexpected, that'd be helpful. I'll type up a quick answer about the most common reason.

Comment: Which Blender version are you using ? (I don't have the exact same buttons on the bottom of the image texture part, and all is moving perfectly fine for me)

Comment: Generally, white color on mesh in textured mode in Blender Internal means there's no texture on it (or no UV map mapping it to the texture). So check that white faces were unwrapped and that they were applied to UV map you set up (not another one).

Comment: How do I check "they were applied to UV map you set up (not another one" ?

Comment: Here is how to do it with Cycles:
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles

Comment: The easiest and fastest way would be to unwrap once more. I meant that faces marked as white could be added / extruded after UV map was made *or* they were unwrapped into another map. Check UV maps you have and islands presented there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Cycles, you will also have to have the image mapped to a material node (like a diffuse or something) before it will show up properly in the Viewport.

Try setting up the material nodes the way they should be, and see if the texture updates better.

The other thing that might be causing this is if your texture is set to repeat. If it's repeating, then when you move a UV island outside the red area, it will still be red. It might be updating... you just can't tell.

Comment: I am using normal blender engine just to avoid dealing with shader nodes.

Comment: I want to say that BI does something similar, where you have to actually set up the material before it'll display properly... but it's been so long since I've used BI...

Comment: Am I not supposed to use Blender Enginge? I am bit confused.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using Blender Internal. It's still supported, and I think it's still being developed, too. I much prefer Cycles, so I use it exclusively.