# How to affix video overlay to 3D model?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, video

I'm looking to make a video demoing an iPhone app. I have an .mp4 file with a video of the interactions on the device. Now, I want to import it into Blender as a 3D plane and affix it to a model of an iPhone so it can be animated.

Here is an example of the effect I am looking for:
https://player.vimeo.com/video/162753618

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: There is an addon you must activate under *File > User Preferences > Addons* called *Import Image as Planes* that should do exactly what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Image Texture Node` for the material applied to the screen portion of the phone. The `Image Texture Node` accepts videos as well.

Remember to UV unwrap your object.

Comment: New to Blender: what does UV unwrap mean?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/8698/32136