# 3D modeling- is it possible to map image to 3d mesh

Tags: 3d-view, uv-image-editor

im a new  to blender as well as 3d modeling....
i have 3d model that i make from other 3d photogrammetry software such as remake..
but the model is not nice... so i want to ask .... is it possible if i want to export the model into blender then map the image onto it.. but the problem is the triangular mesh is too many ( because the model is tree model capture from sequence of photos).. or any solution ..as next i need to export the model into unity to build vr..
thanks..

Comment: Yes, Blender should be totally capable of doing that. Try researching about [UV Mapping](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+UV+mapping&tbm=vid)  and Unwrapping

Answer (score 0):

1. select your object
2. add a new material
3. open the node editor
4. enable "use nodes"
5. add -> texture -> image texture
6. then you can change the position of the texture in the uv editor

That is only a short description. For more information please see the comment from *Duarte Farrajota Ramos*
or look [**here**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles).