# Color all of my models using one texture

Tags: texturing

First of all, I'm not very familiar with texturing.

So what I want to do is have one texture with a selection of colors as such:

[image]

And use that to color my (low poly) models to prevent having to use multiple materials.

If my question still remains unclear. This is what I want my models to look like, by only using one texture.

[image]

**Is this possible?**
Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Absolutely, just move the unwrapped UV to the proper place on the texture.  Would you mind telling me why you only want one texture?  Info on unwrapping UV and applying texture: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles/8698#8698

Comment: Great, I'll just start learning texturing then.

The reason being why I want this is because I'm making models for a game in unity and since they're just low poly models I figure it would be more efficient: fewer textures, less work, less memory.

I saw this concept here: https://youtu.be/rbZJbSru7FA?t=2m27s

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just create a new material and assign it to all faces.
Make it uses the desired texture as diffuse or whatever channel suits you.

Then part by part select the faces of your mesh and unwrap them using any simple method with <kbd>U</kbd> > *Unwrap*

In the *UV/Image Editor* scale down the islands so they fit totally inside one of the nine color cells.

Repeat until you are done. You can readjust them easily by moving each island individually over a desired color.

[image]