# How can I assign different colors in a single material using vertex groups?

Tags: materials, node-editor, vertex-groups, color

I have a material with 8 different colors and my object has 8 different vertex groups. All of the vertex groups have assigned locations on the mesh (robot head). How can I make it so the "HeadWhite" labeled vertex group is colored white (node-labeled), the "HeadLightGrey" labeled vertex group is colored light grey (node-labeled), and so on, within the same material?

EDIT: I'm using diffuse shaders in the picture below as an example, which I placed there for people to test. Once this is answered, I'm going to replace the diffuse shaders with multiple textures and other shaders, so I can't use something like Vertex Colors to do the job.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: If all you want is colors, then use your vertex groups to define UV maps and assign a texure with the colors you want like on this link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84718/color-all-of-my-models-using-one-texture, If what you need are indeed different shaders you can use the same idea from the link, define UVs based on your vertex groups and use the UV mapping to mix different shaders.

Comment: @cegaton I actually wanted a variety of different shaders and textures, I'll add that to my question.

Comment: @PaulGonet Thanks, but that isn't exactly what I'm looking for. I want the colors all within ONE material.

Comment: That will be possible only if you convert vertex group to vertex color by e.g. [Weight And Color](https://github.com/chebhou/Weight-and-Color) addon by @Chebhou and then use that factor from Shift+A>Input>Vertex Colors.

Comment: out of curiosity why do you need them to be a single material? Having different materials would be simpler to manage instead of a spaghetti of nodes..

Comment: @cegaton I want to be able to texture paint stuff onto the robot head, but you can't have multiple materials for texture painting.