# How can I texture my object so that it has two different colors?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

So I have looked at other questions and they do not answer my own so I now resort to typing here.

My problem is visually simple, the texture does not show when plastered onto the UV image. The reason this is a real problem is that the object needs two different colors otherwise I'd be fine. If there is a way I can divide the object into two I would love to hear about it. Thanks in advance for any help that you provide!

[image]

[image]

I removed the image from the nodes here^

Comment: Have you tried giving the object multiple materials?

Comment: Your node tree is wrong: do not plug an image into the volume socket for the material. That input is for shaders only. If the socket is green it should be connected to a green outoput. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33915/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-color-of-the-node-sockets-in-the-node-editor

Comment: You don't need to divide your model nor do you need textures for this. If you really must use textures see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84718/color-all-of-my-models-using-one-texture

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos that is a better duplicate indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if you want to use a UV map on your textures, don´t use the "Generated" link of the Texture Coordinate Node; use the "UV" link instead. And - as said before - don´t connect the color to the volume.

You could simply add two materials to your object (Properties, Material Tab, add two materials), then go to edit mode and manually select the faces which you want one material on, choose the material and click the "assign" button.

An other way is to create BOTH materials in one material by using a mix shader, then create  a black/white UV map (where black = material 1, white = material 2) and plug it in the factor of the mix shader (set the color type to non-color data).