# Render using a fixed color palette for pixel art

Tags: materials, compositing-nodes, pixel-art

I'm looking for a way to have only a set of predetermined colors in my render, to generate pixel-art with those colors only.

The closest I got to the desired effect was by using constant color ramps in materials (like in a simple toon shader node setup), but the colors are not exactly the ones picked once rendered. Using a constant color ramp during compositing failed too since it maps colors by value, and not to the closest color available in the ramp.

Any idea?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84718/color-all-of-my-models-using-one-texture

Comment: About the colors not being quite the same once rendered, have you tried changing the color transform from “filmic“ to standard?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Sorry but this isn't what I'm asking about. I don't just want to use the color palette, I want the only colors in the final render to be those colors, without shade variations.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Thanks, I always forget about this one. Now they are closer to the ones I picked but they still get slightly shaded (with my color-ranped shader), resulting in slights variations of color (which considerably expand the final color palette).

Comment: Hmm. I’m surprised a toon shader system isn’t working for you. One thing I will say is that if you use EEVEE, the emission shader does not actually output light, and thus can be used to make things of solid color.

Comment: @ZargulTheWizard Thanks for the idea, I'll experiment with that.