# How do i insert a picture directly onto the face of a cube?

Tags: uv-image-editor

I have not been able to figure out how, a step by-step process would probably be best.

Comment: What was complex for you to understand from already existing instructions? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles

Answer (score 2):

You can try making a UV Map of the Cube, saving it, and then drawing the texture.
[image: Selecting the Mode]

Go to Edit Mode by pressing [Tab]. Press U and then click "Smart UV Project". You can adjust some of the numbers to change how the texture is generated. You can also change the positon of the sides on the UV Map. To see textures, go to Textured mode

[image: Selecting the Viewport Shading]

To save the UV Map to your preferred destination, click the Export UV Layout as shown below.
[image: Exporting UV Layout]

Afterwards, draw on the sides. You can do a test of which is going to draw on what side by drawing numbers on the UV Map or draw marks in Blender(I think there is a way to do that, but I don't know how).
When you are done making it, save it to your computer and open Blender again and import the image.

[image: Importing an image]

After you have done that, you will see the texture you have done in the Textured rendering.