# Associating photos to the faces of a cube

Tags: mesh

So... I am a beginner in blender and I want to associate those pictures to the faces of the cube, just that they won't show up when I am in the render view. I've watched a few tutorials but still can't make it... Can anybody help me? I want to export the cube in unity.

[image: Face]

[image: Left]

[image: Right]

[image: Back]

[image: Top]

[image: Bottom]

Edit: On a second try... the cube looks perfect blender just how i want it... but on render mode it looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8sdB.jpg and if I import it to unity it is just a blue cube... Help?

Comment: Are you rendering in Cycles or Blender internal?

Comment: please specify which tutorial so to understand which workflow you followed...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpyjqaiE0HI&feature=youtu.be
That's what i followed. When i Use the texture view everything is fine but when I use the render view it shows up like this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

Create 6 different materials (Since you have 6 different images you need to create one material per image).

Have each of the materials use an image as texture.

In Edit mode you need to select a face and **assign** a material to it.

[image]

Repeat that to all of the other faces until each one has a material and each material is using the texture you want.

[image]

[image]

For greater control on how the textures are mapped on the mesh, you need to unwrap the mesh to create UV maps.

Comment: See: [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Answer (score 0):

To see a texture you have applied to a model, you should simply change your Viewport Shading.

[image: Selecting the Viewport Shading]

You will now see the textures you have applied to the cube.
To make them applied in your Unity3D game, you will need to obviously add it to Unity3D and it will look the same as it did when you used the 'Texture' Viewport Shading.

Comment: This doesnt help me...

Comment: Try to use "Smart UV Map Project" in "UV Mapping" mode and texture out the UV map.  A more detailed answer on how to do that: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/100703/how-do-i-insert-a-picture-directly-onto-the-face-of-a-cube/100707#100707