# Image texture on extruded SVG

Tags: texturing, svg

I can't seem to be able to apply a texture to an extruded .SVG.

Note: [How do I put an image texture on a material in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles) does not solve the question as it relates to an older version of Blender: there's nothing like a "grey dot icon on the right side of the Color selector" in my Blender version.

Here's what I do:
1) Import SVG and extrude
[image]
2) Transform to mesh (Mesh from Curve: Alt-C, 2)
[image]
3) Import texture file, and set texture coordinates as "View"
[image]
4) Set the viewport shading to Texture
[image]
5) Notice the the mesh does not get textured properly
6) Go to edit mode to check if something is weird
7) Notice that there IS something fishy
[image]

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks
AC

My materials look like this:

[image]

---

@cegaton: 
This is how my blender looks like:
[image]

If I click on "New" this is what I get:
[image]

While this is what YOU see:
[image]

How can I do it with my GUI?

Comment: Did you create a material?

Comment: Why did you convert your curve to mesh?

Comment: @cegaton: also tried that.. no changes

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I tried to follow that tutorial, but it probably refers to an older version of Blender: there's no such a thing as a "little circle on the far right" in the 'material' section.

No particular reason to convert to mesh.. I'm experimenting as I can't get it to work.

Comment: @EffePelosa Seems that you are using [Blender Internal](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/introduction.html); the other material UI is for [Cycles](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/introduction.html). You can switch with the drop-down in the top header

Comment: ah ahhhh! Thanks Gandalf3!! That made the trick!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to convert the curve to mesh.

- Import the SVG
- Create a material
- Use an image texture in the material
- Select the image you want to use
- Create an empty
- Select your object again and in the materials set the coordinates to object
- Select the empty as the control object for the coordinates.

If you switch to rendered view you should be able to see the texture being used as part of the material of the curve.

[image]

To control the placement and size of the image move/scale/rotate the empty.

[image]

For Blender internal is the exact same procedure: create a material, create a texture, set it to use object coordinates and use an empty to control them.

[image]

Comment: This solution does not work for me... my version of blender (2.79) does not look at all like yours