# apply a wood texture to a circle to make a shield

Tags: 3d-printing

I am attempting to make a old wooden shield for 3d printing.. and would love to have the wood plank texture applied to it..  similar to this.. https://www.artstation.com/artwork/ue4-shield-pack-painted-wooden-round-shield

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put an image texture on a material in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles)

Comment: kinda.. but these instructions are clearer..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course as it's supposed to be in real 3D you can't use a *Normal* or *Bump* node, but you can do it with the *Displace* modifier. And I guess you'll have to apply the modifiers for a 3D printing  ;)

[image]

Comment: Wow... Awesome.. I'll try this when I'm less tired from work..

Comment: ok.. that worked GREAT..  but.. how do I then take that and apply it to the top of a cylinder.. I tried binary but I can't get it to line up.. and ctrl-j smooth away the texture.

Comment: you tried binary? what do you mean? if you want to join it to another object, the apply the different modifiers before joining

Comment: I tried Binary.. but could not get the plain to line up right..  Though I have an Idea of applying it in reverse to a cube.. and then subtract the cube with pattern from the cylinder..

Answer (score 0):

[image]

So used your method to get the image on the cube, made it a negative..

then pulled out a cylinder did a binary difference and tada...  thanks for the insight

Comment: I'm not sure why you used a cube and made a negative but ok  ;)