# How to create a most basic texture on an object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

Can someone please tell me how to create a simple wood texture on the starting cube in Blender 2.8. Every tutorial I can find is linking complicated nodes together or import and mapping jpgs onto meshes.

I've tried going to the texture tab - + - type:wood - set rendering mode to rendered in eevee but its still just a grey cube with no pattern.

How do I make my cube have a texture?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I put an image texture on a material in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles)

Comment: "Every tutorial I can find is linking complicated nodes together or import and mapping jpgs onto meshes."  There are two basic ways to texture an object. One is by importing an image texture, and the other is procedurally generating the texture. (with the complicated nodes). You can indeed make very basic procedural textures without too many nodes, but if you don't want to use an image texture, but still want detail, you will have to use a lot of nodes by necessity.

Answer (score 2):

Most basic approach in Cycles:

1. Unwrap the cube in edit mode.
   [image]
2. Create a new material.
3. In node editor, add an image texture and connect to material node.
   [image]
4. View in render mode.
   [image]

EDIT: You can make textures without nodes... sort of. And you can certainly make textures without using images.

But Blender, Maya, 3ds etc are all node based. You can "hide" this fact by making settings in the data block areas, but nodes are what is really happening... which is to say changes you make in the materials property area, at right in image below, are actually just adjusting nodes. You don't have to "use" nodes, by which I mean see them, but they are their nonetheless.

[image]

Comment: I'm using Blender 2.8

Comment: @Richard - same process.

Answer (score 2):

Importing an image is the only way I can think of (I'm trying to avoid the Node Editor with this solution).

Select the cube, Select Materials, Surface =Diffuse, Color = Image Texture and browse to your wood image (jpg,png,etc).

You will have to be in "LookDev" or "Render" Mode to see it (not wireframe, or solid)

Comment: So you're saying there's an entire tab of textures and an entire tab of materials in Blender and none of them allow you to set the surface of a cube to anything other than the default white plastic without importing an image?  That can't be so.

Comment: @Richard Added an edit at bottom of my original answer.

Comment: Your original question asked for wood so I got specific.   As the first step, I think you'll find most everybody adds a Material using the "new" PBR shader.   It makes most all the other shaders obsolete.   Backward compatibility will keep the others around forever.   It answers how much light is bouncing off and what color is it.   You build your own library of textures and materials (yes - based mostly on images).    A slew of free/affordable 3rd party Add-ons can be utilized.   1000's of users/firms will share their libraries and/or make the functionality of the library itself more powerful