# How to add image on 2 materials?

Tags: materials

I have 2 material and i want to put a image above the 2 material.

[image]

[image]

I have created a bus model and to the below part i have 2 material white and blue. In between on the top of the 2 material i want to add transparent image of ice-cream (as show above.) I have attach the bottom part and icre cream image. How to set up the nodes for it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not clear, you're talking about putting your ice-cream picture in-between the 2 parts but in your screenshot it is on the blue part only. However, what would work in both cases is giving each part its own material, as it is already the case, but reunite the two unwrapped parts, as I've done, and in both the 2 materials, use the same UV (which will be the case by default if you just plug the *Texture Coordinate / UV* output), then use the picture as an overlay like you've already done for one (with the alpha in the factor). With this nodes organization you will control the position of your ice-cream picture just by moving the UV position in the *UV/Image Editor*, whether you want it on one part only or in-between. As the UV is common to both materials, what you decide to do with the UV map will impact both the 2 materials.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have plug the nodes but i get only white material as output. https://imgur.com/a/sVsk9ia I want the icecream cone on the top between 2 materials.

Comment: look at my screenshots, I've tried and it works, whether you want your picture on one part or on both or whatever

Comment: I have connect as shown above. I can just seen half icecream. https://imgur.com/a/e2cfPGz

Comment: im using Blender 2.79b

Comment: you need to do exactly what I've done, re-unwrap and don't touch the UV map, keep the two parts of the UV map together, and use the same nodes organization for both white and blue, as I've done on my screenshots

Comment: ok [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6253" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6253/)

Comment: yes, so UV map is good this time but you didn't do what I've done for the white material, see my screenshot, it's the same as blue material, except the Principled BSDF is white, not blue  ;)

Comment: sorry did not get can u plz share your file. Thanks

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6254" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6254/)

Comment: Thanks got it..