# Apply texture in Blender2.8

Tags: texturing

Recently I downloaded Blender 2.8 (release candidate).
Has Blender no longer had an easy way to apply textures like 2.79?

I want the object to apply the "blend" texture vertically and make the mapping coordinates "UV".
How can I reproduce it in Blender 2.8?
Is Blender 2.8 the only way to use a shader editor?
Sorry to trouble you, but please tell me how.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean compared to 'Blender internal render' in 2.79?

Comment: @lemon I'm not good at English,so I'm sorry if I misinterpret your comment.'I want the object 〜 the mapping coordinates "UV".'This sentence means the operation in Blender2.79.I would like to express this in Blender2.8.

Comment: As far as I know, legacy textures https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/materials/legacy_textures/index.html can no more be used for texturing a model (like in Blender Render for 2.79). They now are more like "tool textures" for use with other functions, like particles influences or displacements. Texturing a model can now be done with node system.

Comment: @lemon Is that so!
After all, does that mean we can no longer use so-called legacy textures?
Thank you for teaching me.
It was very helpful.

Comment: It seems no. But I hope someone else will confirm this.

Comment: That may help you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles

Comment: @lemon Referring to the question page, it seems to work well if I use nodes.　I will try this way.　Thank you for teaching me politely.