# Is it possible to apply textures in Blender 2.8?

Tags: texturing, documentation

I'm following along with Blender's docs, trying to apply a texture to a object's surface. The docs for [Applying Textures](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/uv/applying_image.html) appear to show screenshots of an older version of Blender (perhaps 2.79?), and point to menu items which don't exist in 2.82, such as "Use Alpha in the Map Image panel", and "UV from the Coordinates menu". [This other question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/145903/apply-texture-in-blender2-8) points to the "node system" and indicates that "legacy textures" are no longer supported.

Can textures still be applied using Blender? Was this functionality removed in 2.82, or is it undocumented? Is there documentation available for 2.82, or a better user manual available somewhere?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139621/blender-2-8-do-materials-always-have-textures/139649#139649

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what was missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender 2.8 - do Materials always have Textures?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139621/blender-2-8-do-materials-always-have-textures)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I wasn't familiar with the Shading context, so I was trying to apply textures to the wrong part of the application. Following more tutorials helped me understand how Blender does things.