# How to add image texture to objects material?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, export, texture-baking, unity

I'm trying to convert my ply file into a .fbx or .obj file without losing texture, and I found an answer which details the following steps:

1. UV Unwrap the figure, then bake the vertex paint to a texture.
2. Save this image texture and add it to the object's material.
3. Set the texture mapping coordinates to UV and set to influence the color.
4. Export the file as a .obj file and the obj will keep the object UVs which    can be used to apply the texture correctly

I'm new to Blender so I am afraid I don't understand a lot of things intuitively. I've followed the steps but I am not able to recreate the texture that I can see in Blender, in Unity. It seems to have a dull grey color whereas the original was metallic + black.

I think I have done the UV Unwrapping and the baking part properly. I'm unable to check if my image texture has been saved to the object's material. Is there some way to know if I've made any mistakes in the process? Or is there a better way of doing what I want to achieve?

Details: 
If needed: my .ply file -> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fBj0X7NPygg1BW09rgJPq064odtuI72X/view

After file conversion - I get this .fbx object -> https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Sa_jq78hcrG5wrQ0PLGTxUx2r7ZyyE8p

Screenshots:

Needed texture (seen in blender perfectly)
[image: Needed texture (seen in blender perfectly]

Baking step
[image: Baking step]

Texture saving part
[image: Texture saving part]

Final result in Unity after importing the fbx file (lost the metallic texture)
[image: Final result in Unity after importing the fbx file (lost the metallic texture)]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles/8698#8698 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541