# Blender 2.8 applying image to object

Tags: texturing

I must be missing something obvious.  I am in the texture tab, set up the file paths to the image but I am not getting anything.  Engine is Eevee, Viewport = layout, shading = rendered.

Here are the settings:

[image]

Comment: As you can see in the first menu of the properties panel, you're texturing  a brush, not a material.

Comment: A workable solution can be found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles).

Comment: A python version of this issue is here:  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146746/python-2-8-creating-diffuse-bsdf-in-a-shader-node-when-i-want-it-in-a-surface-n