# Putting an image texture onto a selfmade object

Tags: texturing, image

So what my new Problem is, is that im trying to add the texture u can see on the left side on the picture here:

[image: how it looks like]

to ma knife, and the first row should go from top to bottom on the left side, the other one from top to bottom on the right side. If i add that image texture now, it looks completely muddled up.

Can somebody arrange the picture to fit the knife?
Heres the Download link for the Texture and the Blender Knife...
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qK4hvAY_Ivl-L5L4dlWAW2mz8pjgnP4Q

Thats how i want it to look like:
[image: example]

Comment: Hello and welcome "*Can somebody arrange the picture to fit the knife?*" This site is more of a learning tool than a "fix it for me" forum. Could you rephrase the question so that it focuses on solving the issue rather than have someone do it for you? Also have a [look at other questions about texturing on the site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles/8698), this is a very basic question that has been tackled many time before

Comment: i need an example file to find it out on my own... so any help would be appreciated. Ill just need that one time.

Comment: Hello :). There are many, many issues with the model. I'll adress them in a full answer, including tips on a proper image texturing.

Comment: as long as its understandable imma try and redo it  then ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thre's no need for so much seams.
A very simple UV map is enough.

[image]

1. (Repair the mesh - more steps below) :)
2. Add *just a few* seams where needed
3. Use the UV editor to position the UV map
4. Set image texture to Clip - so it's not repeated across the model.

Using just one material is very limiting, but sometimes needed.
Use more materials if you want different color on your mesh.

*Example of a proper UV unwrap*

[image]

---

How to repair the mesh:

- Apply object scale and rotation through *Object > Apply > All transforms*
- Remove stray and connect unconnected vertices/faces/edges
- Make the mesh manifold (watertight)
- Correct face orientation through *Mesh > Normals > Recalculate outside*
- Delete the old UV map entirely

Here is a repaired .blend for inspiration.
Yours might look a bit different, but that doesn't really matter :).

[image]

Comment: thank you. the problem now is that u removed the holes :/

Comment: the original shape is now gone...

Comment: Sure, it's just for inspiration :). It will work the same with holes in the knife.

Comment: i dont really understand how to use that uv mapping. im a complete beginner.

Comment: In that case, perhaps start with some simple beginner tutorials on YT :). These things are way easier to explain through moving images. Good luck.