# How do you import images onto planes using nodes

Tags: node-editor, add-on, compositing-nodes

I have an image and I want to display it on the plane. I searched Google and found that I can use images as planes but if I ever want to change the image I would have to redo the image and all the stuff *e.g. modifiers and physics* and it's kind of annoying to redo everything so I found out you can use image nodes. I can't seem to find how to put it on the plane.

thanks for any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put an image texture on a material in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an add-on that allows you to automatically import an image as a plane:

[image: images as planes addon]

when you use it to import an image it creates a plane of the right aspect ratio and a shader that displays the image:

[image: images as planes shader]

If you want to change the image, so long as it has the same aspect ratio, all you have to do is click on the file folder and select a new image.

[image: how to change the image]

It can't get any easier than that