# Apply texture at specific area

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

Hi I just start recently using blender, not so expert how to apply texture on the following design.

Actually I used Fusion360 to design this object, in order to have the correct dimension once  I will export it in AR /usdz

[image: pic]

I'm trying to apply the following texture on the marked area, I tried to follow some tutorial how to apply Decals on surface but my surface is curved and sloping so the result is not what I want.

I used the modifier Shrinkwrap but as you can see the result not what I want..

[image]

what I would like is being able to align my texture around the surface marked in the first picture.

looking for some help which option should I watch in blender in order to achieve what I describe.

what I would like is something like in this picture.

[image: final]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I put an image texture on a material in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles) Also https://youtu.be/TMPjKVgTfYs and https://youtu.be/Y7M-B6xnaEM

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78358/how-to-straighten-curved-uvs-into-straight-belt

Answer (score -1):

you can use this node setup for it:

[image]

In my example i added the "less than" node, so you can "crop" the texture if you don't need it all:

[image]

and with another greater than node, you can crop it to both sides:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]