# How do I make a material an image?

Tags: texturing, objects

I want to take a texture that I made using texture paint and add it to my object. I found that it's best add it as a material, and [I found a question that showed me how to do it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/how-do-i-put-an-image-texture-on-a-material-in-cycles) but it's a little confusing and outdated, so does anyone know a good way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: I don't see anything outdated about it. Even today it's still the same process. Just add a image texture node in the shader editor and select your image in it.

Comment: Or rather, it's using the properties editor to add nodes, but it's the same end result as going in the node editor and adding nodes there.

Comment: The fact that it's nine years old, doesn't mean it's outdated. The steps are still the same. Could you clarify what exactly your problem is? For example by explaining what it is that confuses you, or what happens when you try to follow the answers to that question. It will be a lot easier to help, if we know exactly what goes wrong.